# Worse performing k-NN model after hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, hyperparameters

I am evaluating the performance of different machine learning models from the sklearn library on my dataset and comparing each model using four metrics: accuracy, f1 score, logloss and ROC-AUC.

As part of the evaluation, I was intending to tune the hyperparamters for each model and see how much that improves their performances. I initially attempted to tune the kNeighbors classifier hyperparameters, but when using the best parameters obtained from .best_params_, the metrics are worse overall and the f1 score that was used to assess the hyperparameter combinations much worse. Why is this?

See below is my code and the results:

Untuned model:

```
# Fitting model
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Metric evaluation
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
knn_accuracy = knn.score(X_test, y_test)
knn_f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
knn_logloss = log_loss(y_test, y_pred)
y_scores = knn.predict_proba(X_test)
knn_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_scores[:,1])
```

| Accuracy | f1 score | logloss | roc-auc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.759 | 0.222 | 8.34 | 0.493 |

Tuning the model:

```
n_neighbors = list(range(1,30))
p=[1,2,3,4,5]
weights=['uniform', 'distance']

hyperparameters = dict(n_neighbors=n_neighbors, p=p, weights=weights)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

knn_cv = GridSearchCV(knn, hyperparameters, cv=10, scoring='f1')

knn_cv.best_params_
```

Out[107]:
{'n_neighbors': 5, 'p': 5, 'weights': 'distance'}

```
knn_cv = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, p=5, weights='distance')
knn_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = knn_cv.predict(X_test)
knn_accuracy = knn_cv.score(X_test, y_test)
knn_f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
knn_logloss = log_loss(y_test, y_pred)
y_scores = knn_cv.predict_proba(X_test)
knn_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_scores[:,1])
```

| Accuracy | f1 score | logloss | roc-auc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 10.1 | 0.579 |

Comment: One possibility is that GridSearchCV does cross validation to find the best parameters. The best parameters on the cross-validated data might not always be the best ones on your test set.